# What is considered good practice for coding in "real world" situations?

Tags: assembly, comments

I just transferred from a college to a university and it seems like everything I know about proper coding technique is wrong. The way I learned to make code readable was to

- Indent code in body of conditional statements and loops
- Favour creating a new function over having a large block of code
- Comment out code used for debugging or may be used again in future
- Put spaces between operators and arguments e.g. if(a <= b) func1(arg1, arg2,
  arg3)

I lost major marks because

- In assembly code shouldn’t be indented and only labels should be used
  to scan source by eye
- If something can be accomplished without defining a new function, do not do so
- Do not keep old code and have short comments so they do not run into next line
- Do not spaces between arguments and operators

Last thing I bungled up on was first thing in the program it initializes registers to 0 because the simulator used did this but the actual board did not. Is the drawback of this it’s a waste of time? I thought it would help make the code less buggy…

Comment: "In assembly code" There's your problem.  Assembly is primarily meant for computers, not people.  Other programming languages are meant for people first, and the compiler has to do the difficult work of converting human-friendly code into computer-friendly assembly.

Comment: Your instructors may not be right, but they are the ones grading you, so you pretty much have to do things the way the instructor wants. Especially in subjective matters like style, preference or opinion.  Ideally you'll learn what an instructor or TA wants before you have to handle in something that'll be a major part of a grade.

Comment: No one told me assembly is different and it sure makes me mad loosing marks for putting effort into what I thought is good practice. This is a problem of not knowing what I don't know.

Comment: I'm just happy that you're being required to learn assembly, which means you're learning the fundamentals of programming.  Those who graduate with degrees and have never programmed in anything but high-level languages are, in my experience, crippled for the rest of their careers and less effective programmers.

Comment: As for your simulator problem: more experienced people have run into the same issue as you did. In the March 2012 issue of "Nuts & Volts" magazine, Bob Colwell (an architect of the Pentium Pro - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Colwell) relates a brief anecdote about how Intel performed much of the testing for the Pentium Pro on a simulator that reset flip-flops on powerup. It was basically an accident that they discovered that the simulator needed to change to init them to a random state. Several problems were fixed before ship only because of the off-hand comment that prompted the change.

Comment: Assembly doesn't really have much indentable concepts such as a "nicely scoped block", you can jump around in ways Dijkstra wouldn't like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rules (except for the commenting out code) are generally still considered good practice. However, they may not apply as nicely to assembly as they do to other languages. Assembly programming is a specific beast so it might can have different style rules/best practices.

With that said, your original rules still apply to pretty much any other programming language.

Also, regarding commenting out code. This is usually considered bad practice, since commented out code often gets left behind and confuses the next generation of developers. Generally, your source control system makes it easy to get back delete code, so you shouldn't comment it out to preserve it.

Answer (score 4):

As many have pointed out thus far, it is very important to make the difference between a high level language and a low level language.

High level languages implement many constructs which enable us, puny humans, to translate our ideas as close to the original as possible. We have object oriented design, data oriented design, prototype oriented design... All of which is meant to give humans an upper hand at describing things in a readable and maintainable manner.

In almost every case, this costs performance (in relation to assembly languages which are just a layer of abstraction away from machine code). Even some of the things that are considered good practice with object oriented design force the computer to do unnecessary work which just stomps on performance. This could be anything from unnecessary loadhitstores, cache misses (both instruction and data) by lousy modeling of data by programmers. Getters and setters hit the number one bloat of regular OO design. And right after them are programmers who don't think about what they write.

At a lower level, your job is to appease the computer, not your sense of aesthetics. You're juggling registers, memory addresses, loading, writing of data. It needs to be the way the given hardware architecture likes it.

I don't agree with some of the ideas your teachers have about good practices, especially if they are enforced in high-level languages. As I've said, if it doesn't hamper performance, looks nice and readable, it becomes your style of getting things done. And punishing individuality is, in my opinion... Well, let's just say not nice.

And most importantly, you must appease the teachers. They can be a hard bunch to deal with. Even if they are wrong, you have to accept it and play their game. Try to argument your side, ask what they want from you and you'll be fine.

Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 2):

The rules people go by for high-level languages vs assembly languages vary a lot.

(when I refer to something being obvious, I mean to another programmer that has around as much experience as you do, not obvious to a random journalism student, or something)

In general, good practices in any situation:

1. Give a brief comment whenever the purpose of a variable/register isn't immediately obvious
2. Avoid the obvious comments (i.e. saying that a counter counts is kinda redundant)
3. In submitted work, remove all unnecessary comments
4. Limit line length to 80 characters (keeps code neat-looking and easy-to-read)

As far as specific languages go, you now seem to have a pretty decent grasp on the right standards.  Basically apply your first list to everything but assembly and assembly-like languages, and your second list to assembly.

Also, you don't need to initialize registers, because they have default known values upon startup.  Initialization in higher-level languages is typically mandated by teachers because some cases require it and some cases don't, and it is far easier (and safer) to just have you initialize everything.  EDIT:  I'm assuming that you're working with an ARM or AVR board for this last paragraph.  I think others are the same way, but I'm not positive...

Comment: Yes I'm working on an Embest board with ARM architecture. Someone told me it doesn't initialize the registers to 0 (or whatever) when a program is loaded. Out of curiousity how would you find out asside from reading the manual?

Comment: Typically I just read the manual.  Ctrl+F is definitely your friend here (searching for Initial Value, initialize, or just finding the register description page tends to work well)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you were first taught good practices for writing in a high level language.

Your new school wants you to program using a low level language. The Best Practices are completely different for both. You just need to know which practices apply to which language.

Answer (score 0):

I think your style guidelines for high-level code are similar to what are generally taught.  As others have noted, though, assembly is a different type of programming.  For example, it's often better to write a specific subroutine to (say) multiply by 6 than to have a general purpose subroutine to multiply arbitrary numbers.  This is because assembly programs are generally used for time or space-critical applications, where the overhead inherent in a general-purpose function call just gets in the way.  This also leads to repeating code with slight modifications (e.g. multiply by 6, multiply by 10, etc.), and even repeating instructions (incrementing a register 3 times is often faster than adding 3 to it, since addition must be done in the accumulator, whose current value may need to be preserved, carry cleared, and so on).

It gets weirder: sometimes a subroutine will jump directly to another subroutine without returning (a "tail call"); sometimes the program will push an address on the stack, and then return from a subroutine (i.e. execute an RET or RTS instruction) without calling a subroutine first: this lets you branch to a large number of different routines without first doing a long series of compare/branch statements.  Oftentimes, assembly programs have date interleaved with the code, with jump or branch instructions to make sure the data is never executed (since to the computer, a valid opcode is just a hexadecimal sequence).

It's difficult and often frustrating, but the rewards of learning assembly language programming are tremendous: you will understand precisely what a computer program does (and how it does it) in a way that others do not.  Good luck!